# Java - get class properties by string

Tags: java

How can I return a property with String name of it inside a class?
My pseudo code is:

```
class Foo {
    public static final String test = "test";

    public static String bar(String name) {
        return foo.getProperty(name);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I have a class with "setting" name , and this class have a method with getSetting() name , this method get a string key and if a property exist with this key, return the property , if no , search in database for this key,it's nod good solution?

Comment: to start off, I would declare bar() to be returning a `String` or *void* or something in your code. PS : I didn't get your question.

Comment: What does _foo_  means . is it instance of class Foo ? if yes then show the code of getProperty() Method of Class Foo

Comment: it's just simple.not my class

Answer (score 0):

Try [Java Reflection - Fields](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/fields.html) with #getFields();

In your scenario, you can try:

```
public String getSetting(String strKey){
        Class tmp = setting.class;    
        try {
            Field field = tmp.getField(strKey);
            return value; // depend on your class instance or  field type.
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // get data from database and return
        } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks , whats happen when the field not found?

Comment: @user3929483 just create a program and test it.

Comment: @user3929483 why do you want to do in this way? See [Drawbacks of Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Comment: @user3929483: NoSuchFieldException

Comment: @user3929483 Just catch and handle by your way :)

Comment: I cannot get property value , it's just an object :(

Comment: How can i access to non-static methods with this case?

Comment: @Chris It depend on your class instance, please update your question.